# How to set a div in front of its own content?

Tags: html, drag-and-drop, z-index, draggable, drag

I'm trying to drag and drop divs around within a bigger div.
In the divs is a title and an image. The Problem is that I can't click on the img or text to drag the whole div. How can I set the div in front his own content?

```
<div class="bigDiv">
    <div class="littleDiv1" draggable="true">
        <p class=title1>Title1</p>
        <img src="#" class="img1" draggable="false">
    </div>
    <div class="littleDiv2" draggable="true">
        <p class=title2>Title2</p>
        <img src="#" class="img2" draggable="false">
    </div>
    <div class="littleDiv3" draggable="true">
        <p class=title3>Title3</p>
        <img src="#" class="img3" draggable="false">
    </div>
</div>
```

I tried also with `draggable="false"` but it doesn't work. I tried with the z-index too, but it worked neither.

Comment: you need to set `position` style  to made `z-index` work !!

Comment: Position: relative?

Comment: Yes `position:relative` and `z-index:10000!important` for exemple !

Comment: Okay I've set the z-index of the img and title to -1. It worked! 
thank you :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to use `z-index` and set `position` style for that.

So for exemple, you can add this to your div style :

```
position:relative; 
z-index: 1000!important;
```